# Looping round array and concatenating results Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop, active-directory, ldap

Please see my code below, I am interrogating active directory and retrieving back two fields, "name" and "cn".  I want to concatenate these in an array and then assign to my drop down list.  i.e.   name + ' ' + cn.  The code below publishes my results wrongly and is displaying all names and cn as individual results i.e. not concatenated.

Can someone advise me and put me in the right direction?

thanks,
George

```
try 
{
    // Get LDAP Context 
    ctx = LdapServices.getLdapContext();

    //Specify the search scope
    ctls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.ONELEVEL_SCOPE);

    var searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=group))";

    //Specify the Base for the search
    var searchBase = "ou=Licensed Applications,ou=SCCM Apps,ou=Applications,ou=Groups,dc=XXX,dc=XX,dc=XX";

    //initialize counter to total the group members
    var totalResults = 0;

    //Specify the attributes to return
    var returnedAtts=["name", "cn"];
    ctls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAtts);

    //Search for objects using the filter
    var answer = ctx.search(searchBase, searchFilter, ctls);

    //Loop through the search results
    while (answer.hasMoreElements()) 
    {
        var sr = answer.next();

        var attrs = sr.getAttributes();
        if (attrs != null) 
        {
            try 
            {
                for (var ae = attrs.getAll();ae.hasMore();) 
                {
                    var attr = ae.next();
                    var pos = attr.toString().indexOf(":",0);
                    var attributeName = attr.toString().substring(0,pos);

                    var name = "";
                    var cn = "";                    

                    for (var e = attr.getAll();e.hasMore();totalResults++) 
                    {
                            if(attributeName == "name")
                            {
                                name = e.next().replace('SCCM_','');
                            }

                            if(attributeName == "cn")
                            {
                                cn = e.next();
                            }
                    } 

                    listItems.push(name + ' (' + cn + ')');
                }
            } 
            catch (e) 
            {
                log("Problem listing items: " + e);
            } 
        }
    }
} 
catch (e) 
{
    log("Problem searching directory: " + e);
}
finally
{
    // Close LDAP Context
    ctx.close();
}
```

Comment: if `listItems.push(name+' ('+cn+')')` pushes non-concatenated `name` and `cn`, then the problem is outside of the code you showed us, because this is clearly a proper concatenation.

Comment: Yes, I am guessing there is a problem with one or more of my loops.  But I cannot see where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what javascript library you use to have JNDI like code into, but from the purely LDAP point of view :

An attribute can be multi-valued, so every attributes value are returned in a array, even if single valued (possible exception for the `dn`), for example :

```
{
 "dn":"cn=user,dc=example,dc=com",
 "name":["username"],
 "cn":["commonname"]
}
```

If your library works like JNDI, a way to do it could be :

After the line : `var attrs = sr.getAttributes();`

```
if (attrs != null) {
  try {
    log ("name: " + attrs.get("name").get());
    log ("cn: " + attrs.get("cn").get());
  } catch (e) {
    log ("Problem listing attributes from Global Catalog: " + e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  Marked as answer.

Comment: @GeorgeGeorgiou Can you tell me which is the javascript library you use or the context you use it in ?